# Creating a login section - Im new an need some serious direction please!

Tags: authentication, login-script

Alright.  So I am new, I know my way around html pretty well, and have gotten by for a while now doing so. But today I am presented with a seemingly simple issue.

My client needs the ability for users to create their own LOGIN/PASSWORD, my client wants to be able to MANUALLY approve visitors. And he want to be able to track how many times they login.

The login section will just be about 4 pages of PDF file downloads.

I cant imagine this is the hardest thing in the world, I just have no clue where to even start. Perhaps there is a code already written, as things like this are done every day using forum technologies...

Please help!

It may also help to mention that I am using Dreamweaver cs4 on a MAC

Comment: What technology stack are you going to use?  That will make your answer vary greatly.  ASP.NET? Ruby on Rails? Python? What?

Comment: The first thing you need to answer is, what web server are you developing for? there are two main ones: AMP - apache, mysql, php - and IIS - microsoft internet information server - which runs asp scripts. Each has its own means for managing authenticated users.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) if I were you. It's pretty easy to get something quick up with it that you can have users create accounts with that send e-mails to the client with approve/reject options, and be able to track downloads and users via [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) or other databases.

I've found [Agile Development with Rails](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails) to be a great source of info on how to do stuff like this (they do an online bookstore as the book's example) and with a little modification I think it should work for what you say you want to do (and the book is pretty cheap as far as programming books go).

Comment: im looking into ruby on rails right now, though im not exactly where to even start. all I can find is a windows installer?   Im on a mac.

Comment: Check out here (http://rubyonrails.org/download). If you're on OS X 10.4, there's a link there on how to get it going, and if you're on 10.5 all you need to do is install the developer tools (probably the second disk that came with your mac) and then type in "gem update rails" at the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just really basic static login features without lots of coding, you can start with [Password protecting your pages with htaccess](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/). You can password protect directories like this without any effort at all. This way, you can be sure that your login routine is secure.

Then, you can continue with advanced features like account administration and login statistics. These will require some programming skills.

Tracking count of user logins should be easy too. You can put simple PHP code to the source of protected pages that will save the info about login to the database. This will require you to study some basics of databases. You can use plaintext files which is not as clean but much easier and it will allow you to export info for your client more easily.

If you want to do it profesionally, you should invest in learning about web development or hire someone to do it for you. These tasks might not be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Have you worked with PHP, ASP.Net or some other web language yet? What you're trying to isn't too difficult in the grand scheme of things but it may be somewhat challenging if you haven't programmed before and/or haven't had any experience with web development.

(P.s. Alter your question as a response and comment on my answer when you're finished.)

Comment: I have worked with web design alot, just strictly html. Until now I have never had a need to have a log in section, aside from systems prebuilt into things like Gallery2 and Phpbb based forums...

Comment: Well you're going to need to learn a web programming language. Where are you hosting this website currently? In house or some provider? Do you know if they allow for Ruby On Rails, ASP, ASP.Net, ColdFusion or PHP? Do they give you a database to work with?

Comment: I host with Godaddy.   I get support in most languages...  I have mysql databases

Comment: I'd recommend going with PHP then. As you can see Chris Bunch is recommending Ruby but I haven't had any experience with it so I can't say if it's easier or harder to work with.

Comment: Im looking into his suggestion now.   If that doesnt work out for me, do you know of any other services that may be of help?

Comment: For a non programmer, it would be very hard to come up with secure login. I would really start with htaccess and then think about extending it programatically.

Comment: i already have a system in place.   So now i need to being looking into ACTUALLY providing the options that were requested. 

User created access
Login tracking

Thank you for the help by the way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by services but there are lots of examples on the web that can help you along. Learn to work with MySQL, grasp the basics of creating tables, learn a minimal amount of SQL, learn the basics of a web language, connect to mySQL with your web language etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking into Ruby on Rails, take a look at [bort](http://jimneath.org/2008/09/09/bort-base-rails-application/) which is a RoR app skeletton with RESTful authentication included, it should help (Chris Bunch answered on the general RoR question).

There is also this [bort fork](http://matthall.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/a-bort-fork-rails-base-application/).  There is also [Authlogic](http://www.railsinside.com/plugins/145-authlogic-another-take-on-rails-authentication.html) which may be easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ASP.net Membership provider and also the login controls which provides the UI for the login as well as registration screens out of the box.
   Here is a [Multipart Series on ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506094439/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060706-1.aspx)

If this is too complex than probably you can also design you application from scratch using ASP.net. If you don't know asp.net than the best place to start is [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net) it has several videos and tutorials which would help you get going soon.